# Child process sends a number through a pipe, then waits

Tags: c, pipe, sleep

I'm trying to spawn two child processes connected with a pipe.
Child 1 is supposed to send a number through a pipe to child 2 and child 2 should print it. I managed to do that, but when I try to do this in a loop, with child 1 waiting 1 second each time before sending another number, it doesn't send anything.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1) {
        pid_t pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2) { //parent
            // do stuff as parent
        } else { //child 2
            close(fd[1]);
            char stringNumberReceived[10];
            while (1) {
                read(fd[0], stringNumberReceived, sizeof (stringNumberReceived));
                printf("number received: %s\n", stringNumberReceived);
            }
        }
    } else {//child 1
        close(fd[0]);
        int num;
        char stringnumber [10];
        while (1) {
            num = rand();
            snprintf(stringnumber, 10, "%d", num);
            printf("attempting to sent: %s\n", stringnumber);
            write(fd[1], stringnumber, strlen(stringnumber) + 1);
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could start by checking what `write` *and* `read` returns. If they return `-1` something failed and you need to check `errno` to see what's wrong (using e.g. `perror` to print it out). Also, if `read` return `0` it means the other end of the pipe was closed, check for that too.

Comment: You should also add error checking for the `pipe` and `fork` calls as well. The `close` function can *also* fail, but the likelihood of that happening when passing the correct descriptor is slim to none, so it's usually okay to not check that one.

Comment: okay i tried it and also checked that the pipe and fork calls were succesfull and i changed the code a bit. ouput:                                                                          attemting to sent: 148176593
number received: 148176593
attemting to sent: 108537774

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s). the problem is that the write function fails and doesnt return anything when i try to send the number for a second time. If I do it without the Sleep(1000), write() manages to send a bunch of numbers but as soon as read reads the first one, the program stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a mildly modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_COUNT = 20 };

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1)
    {
        pid_t pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2)   // parent
        {
            printf("Child 1: %d; child 2: %d\n", (int)pid1, (int)pid2);
            close(fd[0]);   // Let the child detect EOF!
            close(fd[1]);   // Let the child detect EOF!
            int corpse;
            int status;
            while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
                printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
        }
        else     // child 2
        {
            close(fd[1]);
            char stringNumberReceived[10];
            int nbytes;
            while ((nbytes = read(fd[0], stringNumberReceived, sizeof(stringNumberReceived))) > 0)
                printf("number received: %.*s\n", nbytes, stringNumberReceived);
            printf("Child 2: EOF or ERR\n");
        }
    }
    else    // child 1
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        int num;
        char stringnumber[10];
        for (int counter = 0; counter < MAX_COUNT; counter++)
        {
            num = rand();
            snprintf(stringnumber, sizeof(stringnumber), "%d", num);
            printf("attempting to send: [%s] (len %zu)\n", stringnumber, strlen(stringnumber));
            write(fd[1], stringnumber, strlen(stringnumber) + 1);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What changed?  Various things.  You can ignore the changes in placement of braces; that's purely cosmetic.

1. Parent code is implemented.
2. Parent reports child process IDs.
3. Parent closes the pipe — it is neither reading nor writing.
4. Parent waits for children to die, reporting statuses as they do.
5. Child records how many bytes it read, and ensures it prints no more than that.
6. It terminates the loop and reports before exiting when it gets an error or EOF (0 bytes read) on the pipe.
7. Other child does a fixed number of cycles (20 as shown) before exiting.
8. If the random number generator ever generates a 10+ digit number, you could have array bounds problems.  The maximum length I got was 9, which is just safe.
9. Generating child could/should report when it is done.

Of the changes, I suspect that close the pipe in the parent may be the key one.

Sample output (on a Unix machine):

```
$ pp43
attempting to send: [16807] (len 5)
Child 1: 69198; child 2: 69199
number received: 16807
attempting to send: [282475249] (len 9)
number received: 282475249
attempting to send: [162265007] (len 9)
number received: 162265007
attempting to send: [984943658] (len 9)
number received: 984943658
attempting to send: [114410893] (len 9)
number received: 114410893
attempting to send: [470211272] (len 9)
number received: 470211272
attempting to send: [101027544] (len 9)
number received: 101027544
attempting to send: [145785087] (len 9)
number received: 145785087
attempting to send: [145877792] (len 9)
number received: 145877792
attempting to send: [200723770] (len 9)
number received: 200723770
attempting to send: [823564440] (len 9)
number received: 823564440
attempting to send: [111543816] (len 9)
number received: 111543816
attempting to send: [178448449] (len 9)
number received: 178448449
attempting to send: [74243042] (len 8)
number received: 74243042
attempting to send: [114807987] (len 9)
number received: 114807987
attempting to send: [113752250] (len 9)
number received: 113752250
attempting to send: [144128232] (len 9)
number received: 144128232
attempting to send: [16531729] (len 8)
number received: 16531729
attempting to send: [823378840] (len 9)
number received: 823378840
attempting to send: [143542612] (len 9)
number received: 143542612
Child 2: EOF or ERR
PID 69198 exited with status 0x0000
PID 69199 exited with status 0x0000
$
```